# How do I make the Structured Indentation lines solid in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

Instead of having dotted vertical lines underneath each `{`:

[image]

It used to to have solid lines:

[image]

I know you can turn these lines off and change their color. (Found these answers while searching.) But what happened to the line style?

Comment: He is wondering how to turn the vertical lines underneath each { solid. Seems like a pretty clear question to me.

Comment: I've messed with the settings for quite a while. I am not sure of why this change occurred. It's possible that people who are downvoting don't know explicitly what "structured indentation guidelines" are.

Comment: What does it mean to make lines solid? What indentation are you referring to? Which line?

Comment: The code blocks seem to be unrelated. Why? It doesn't help us understanding which line gives the problem.

Comment: In one of the images, the structured indentation lines. (the dotted ones) are dotted. In the second they are much softer and solid. I cannot figure out how to return them to a solid line instead of a dotted one.

Not lines of code, literal vertical lines (structured indentation guidelines,) in the text editor.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the question to make it clearer. I understood it just fine but apparently others didn't :)

Comment: I saw that, I appreciate it! :) 

Just started using this website, so I'm not very good about asking questions.

Comment: Ah, you are not talking about the indentation itself, but the lines that connect the two opposite brackets.

Comment: The "tools" menu calls them "structured indentation guidelines." Thus the confusion. Anyway, the old ones were really nice for keeping the code in line (literally) but now they have been changed to this thick and intrusive dotted pattern. I detailed above that I can change the color or just turn them off, but I can't seem to change the style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable the lines with the option *Show guides for declaration level constructs* under *Text Editor* > *C#* > *Advanced* > *Block Structure Guides*.

Since Visual Studio 2017 Update 2, the soft line has been replaced by the dotted one. As far as I can see there is no option to change the dotted line back to the softer one. You can suggest this feature using [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback).

Comment: Okay so I am not crazy, that's good to hear, it was just some recent update.

Thanks! I'll suggest the option on Connect. :)

Comment: No problem! I'll work on my question proposition for next time.

Comment: Connect is retired as of 2018

Answer (score 0):

You can install the "Indent Guides for VS 2022" Visual Studio extension and then Go to
Tools > Options > Indent Guides > Appearance> HighLigt Style > solid.